# This day in history V

Tags: riddle, history

Well done to Beastly Gerbil who got the answer to This day in history IV. Something happened on 4th May a certain number of years ago. Can you tell me what it was and how many years ago it happened?

In a city that borders Lake Michigan
Drew the attention of 200 policemen
With 1.5k where it took place
And it set off a hate of race

Then, after something exploded
A dozen or so kicked it
31 were arrested
And seven were executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is most probably the **Haymarket affair** which occurred in Chicago on **4 May 1886**.

In a city that borders Lake Michigan

> Chicago, Illinois borders Lake Michigan

Then, after something exploded

> A homemade bomb was burst

You can read about the event 
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haymarket_affair)

Comment: Well done! Are you able to provide the full explanation of the lines

Comment: I'll try and add more but I think that rot13(gur bgure yvarf ner engure frys rkcynangbel nsgre ernqvat gur negvpyr.)

Comment: Ahh, yea. Nvrmind